# How to sort model by the existence of attachment in eloquent? I need first to display the model with the existing attachment

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried this

```
$arElementIDList =  Product::withCount(['preview_image'])->
    active()
        ->orderBy('preview_image_count', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: what version of laravel are you using? and what is the output to this query? what do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: This query does not sort by the presence of attachment

Comment: I use laravel 5.5, database MySQL

Comment: What's the result of `dd(Product::withCount(['preview_image'])->active()->orderBy('preview_image_count', 'desc')->toSql());`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Product::whereNotNull('preview_image')->orderBy('preview_image_count', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: preview_image is hasOne relation, so it doesn't work

Comment: replace preview_image by the name of the column which stores attachment name/link